# Weblogc BEA-000449 : Closing socket as no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I have started seeing this message in my weblogic 10 log files. 
   
I am running an app with around 40-350 concurrent users. My questions are

1. What does this error really mean
2. How will it affect the users (if it does)
3. What could be causing this

thanks

Comment: We have the same problem and it seems to be related to using Chrome as the browser. Using any other browsers, I don't see this message in the log. Accessing the same pages in Chrome, I'll get 2 or 3 of this message after each page is refreshed. I assume it's something related to how Chrome is opening and closing connections, but I'd bank on the problem being on the Weblogic side even so.

Comment: for me this is happening in firefox while trying in IE it is working

Comment: This is happening for me in Chrome and IE. A popup freezes with the label "fetching data". Does the BEA-000449 has something to do with the freezing?

Answer (score 5):

> What does this error really mean

Weblogic is closing a socket used to communicate with one of the server's clients because no data has been sent for more than five seconds, which is the value you have configured for Weblogic's idle timeout.

> What could be causing this

Client programs connecting to your server, sending some data, and then either 1) not closing the connection or 2) disappearing.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from Oracle's document:

E-WL: WebLogic Logs Warning Message: "`<BEA-000449>` Closing socket as no data read from it on xx.xxx.xxx.xxx during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs" (Doc ID 1423761.1)

> The message is a warning and typically has no user impact, thus no action needs to be taken.
>
> Note that there is an option to filter out the 'Closing socket' messages, as described below. But we advise against doing this since there is a small chance that the messages could be indicative of some sort of issue in your environment, therefore it is good to be aware of whether these messages are logged and the frequency at which they are logged. However, if still choose to filter out the messages, you can do so as follows:
>
> 1. Log into WebLogic Admin console
> 2. Click the 'Lock & Edit' button on left menu
> 3. First, add the log filter:
>
>    a. Click on your PeopleSoft Domain Name (on left menu in the 'Domain Structure' section)
>       b. Go to 'Configuration' tab and 'Log Filters' subtab
>       c. Click 'New' button to create a new filter
>       d. Give any name to your new log file (eg "LogFilter-ClosingSocket'
>       e. Click 'OK'
>       f. Now click on the hyperlink for the newly created filter and in the 'Current Log Filter Expressions', click edit button to add the following:
>                NOT(MESSAGE LIKE 'Closing socket as no data read from it%')
>       g. Save the change
>       h. Click 'Activate Changes' button on left menu
>
> 4. Now assign the filter to the server
>
> a. On left menu, choose Environment->Servers
>      b. On right menu, click the hyperlink for server you wish to update (eg 'PIA')
>      c. Choose 'Logging' tab and 'General' subtab
>      d. Go to bottom of page and click 'Advanced' hyperlink
>      e. Click 'Lock & Edit button
>      f. In the 'Logging' section, add the new filter that you created (in step 3 above)
>      g. Also add the filter to the 'Standard out' section (so that message is not logged to PIA_weblogic.log nor the stdout/ntservice log)
>      h. Save the change
>       i. Click 'Activate Changes' button on left menu

Comment: Never, ever copy-paste a whole block of stuff without citing your source. And before doing that, make sure you're _allowed_ to reproduce things verbatim under the CC licence, I have no idea if Oracle allows that. Also if you want to put contact info, use your profile's "About me" section.

Answer (score 0):

**BEA-000449**

**Warning**: Closing socket as no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of idleTimeout secs

**Description**: Closing socket as no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of idleTimeout secs

**Cause**: The WebLogic Server or the network may be overloaded which is causing the socket to idle timeout.

**Action**: Capacity tuning of the server is required.

source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e14397/Socket.html

Answer (score -1):

## Action:Capacity tuning of the server is required.

Please set the parameter -Dweblogic.client.socket.ConnectTimeout=XXX, in
startupscript of the AdminServer, and all the managed servers under JAVA_OPTIONS and check whether it is showing the same behaviour or not, where "XXX" is the value in ms.

```
-Dweblogic.client.socket.ConnectTimeout=500
```

Referred from : https://community.oracle.com/thread/695621

Comment: You did not answer his questions ->
"What does this error really mean
How will it affect the users (if it does)
What could be causing this"