# How to configure the Closing socket as no data read for session timeout

Tags: sockets, weblogic, weblogic11g

I need your help in getting rid of the below warning because it is stopping me of doing any activity in the jsf page:

> Socket BEA-000449 Closing socket as no data read from   it on
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXX during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs

I tried changing the session timeout in web.xml, but still it shows the above warning:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>200</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

Comment: You changed the wrong thing. Session timeout != socket idle timeout.

Comment: @EJP So where should I change?

Comment: Have you edited your server start params to include: `-Dweblogic.client.socket.ConnectTimeout=<some number>` See: https://community.oracle.com/message/11124702  or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973822/weblogc-bea-000449-closing-socket-as-no-data-read-from-it-during-the-configure

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAVA_OPTIONS to set this parameter.
In you start script add the following Java option:

```
-Dweblogic.client.socket.ConnectTimeout=XXX
```

where XXX is value in ms.
Also you can read the following thread from Oracle:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2125724