# <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on IP Address:52,750 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am getting this error in my local server and i couldn't able to access my application and i referred the same in stack overflow and found ""[Weblogc BEA-000449 : Closing socket as no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973822/weblogc-bea-000449-closing-socket-as-no-data-read-from-it-during-the-configure)" and some other  but none of the solution works. If any one is having idea regarding this please let me know.

Even I changed the Settings of Weblogic Admin console as well as my local server Configuration--> tuning---> Login Timeout: to 5000(ms) to 50000(ms) still no use . Please help me to get rid of this.